# index of a String in a paragraph each time it occurs

Tags: java

```
String word="i love apples i love orange";
String w=scan.next();
    int index = word.indexOf(w);
    System.out.println (index);
while (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println(index);
    index = word.indexOf(w, index + 1);
}
```

so i know that this code will tell me the index of love is (2,17)
but what im looking for is that i want it to return for me the index of the word to be (1,4) that is it counts the strings within the string and not the characters...also i need it to indicate the index each time it finds it like the one above thanks

Comment: Split your string by word and count.

Comment: i tried using a for loop to loop over the string word length but also its counting the characters i dont understand why

Comment: ok so i split them using an array String[] a=word.split(" "); then how can i count a word that the user enter?

Comment: If you solve your problem, choose the answer, that help you, and fix it as "accepted". If you find your own decision, create your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your variable "word" words seperates only with using spaces, you can use such code

```
String word="i love apples i love orange";
String w=scan.next();
String[] words = word.split(" ");
for (int i=0; i< words.length; i++){
    if (words[i].equals(w)){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
If you would like to count words try this -

```
String word="i love apples i love orange";
String w=scan.next();
String[] words = word.split(" ");
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i< words.length; i++){
    if (words[i].equals(w)){
        System.out.println(i);
        count ++;
    }
}
System.out.println("Count = "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finds the position of the input within the word and the position of the word within the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int lastIndex = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String w = scan.next();

    String word = "i love apples i love orange";
    String[] tokens = word.split(" ");

    for (String token : tokens) {
        if (token.contains(w)) {
            for (int x = 0; x < token.length(); x++) {
                System.out.println("Input found in token at position: " + (token.indexOf(w) + 1));
            }

            System.out.println("Word found containing input in positions: " + (word.indexOf(token, lastIndex) + 1)
                    + "-" + ((word.indexOf(token, lastIndex)) + token.length()));
            lastIndex = ((word.indexOf(token,lastIndex)) + token.length());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code find the string (needle) inside the paragraph (str) each time it occours.
The needle can contain spaces, and the word index is printed each time.

```
String str = "i love apples i love orange";
String needle = "i love";
int wordIndex = 0;
for (int start = 0; start < str.length(); start++) {
  if (Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(start))) wordIndex++;
  if (str.substring(start).startsWith(needle)) {
    System.out.println(wordIndex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package JavaPractice;

public class CountNumberOfWords {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "My name is srikanth. srikanth is working on a java program. " + 
            "srikanth dont know how many errors atr there. so, " +
            "srikanth is going to find it.";
    String Iwant = "srikanth";
    int wordIndex = 0;
    int count =0;
    for (int start = 0; start < str.length(); start++) {
      if (Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(start))) wordIndex++;
      if (str.substring(start).startsWith(Iwant)) {
        System.out.println("Index of the String Iwant "+wordIndex);
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of times srikanth in str is="+count);

}
}
```

Output:

```
Index of the String Iwant 3
Index of the String Iwant 4
Index of the String Iwant 11
Index of the String Iwant 20
Number of times srikanth in str is=4
```

Comment: Try formatting the code so it is readable.   There are facilities when editing your post.   As is, it is not altogether clear that you have even answered the question.